# Search for an XML node in a parent by string with python

Tags: python, xml

I'm working with python xml.dom. I'm looking for a particular method that takes in a node and string and returns the xml node that is is named string. I can't find it in the documentation

I'm thinking it would work something like this

`nodeObject =parent.FUNCTION('childtoFind')`

where the nodeObject is under the parent

Or barring the existence of such a method, is there a way I can make the string a node object?

Comment: Any specific reason you cannot use the [ElementTree API](http://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html) instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for the [`.getElementsByTagname()` function](http://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.dom.html#xml.dom.Element.getElementsByTagName):

```
nodeObjects = parent.getElementsByTagname('childtoFind')
```

It returns a list; if you need only one node, use indexing:

```
nodeObject = parent.getElementsByTagname('childtoFind')[0]
```

You really want to use the [ElementTree API](http://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html) instead, it's easier to use. Even the [`minidom` documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.dom.minidom.html) makes this recommendation:

> Users who are not already proficient with the DOM should consider using the `xml.etree.ElementTree` module for their XML processing instead.

The ElementTree API has a `.find()` function that let's you find the first matching descendant:

```
element = parent.find('childtoFind')
```

Comment: Thank you, this is helpful. I was hoping it wasn't in the documentation. I didn't see the ElementTreeAPI thing directly referenced in the documentation. I'll take a look at it.